# Database design for tree data with a large table (+- 5.000.000 rows)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've got a dataset which is going to result in a tree in a MySQL table. I'm facing about 5.000.000 rows with a maximum depth of 6 levels from the top to the bottom. The data type is geographical, like country, province/state etc (and not covering the whole world, obviously).

```
// This is the tree design
Top level (population: a few)
  Sub level (population: a few more)
    Sub sub level (population: a little more)
      Sub sub sub level (population: a few hundred)
        Sub sub sub sub level (population: a few thousand)
          Sub sub sub sub sub level (population: millions)
```

One way to store this would be to use a foreign key that refers to the parent id in the table but I'm a bit concerned about performance if I have to get a full tree upon request to display.

Another way would be to seperate the data in leveled tables. But still, most rows (over 99%) will still be kept in one table, while the other "parent" tables would contain a few to a few thousand rows. So this is not really an option.

A last way I could think about is to vertically divide the most detailed table. Each row is coded like AAAAA00000. So I could split for the first character, resulting in 26 table "partitions".

The Nested Set Model is no option in this case because it would result in a massive update correcting the new right-value when a new record is added.

What would be your bet? Or would you set this up using a total different approach?

Comment: Is this more like 'genealogy', wherein 'persons' are at every level?  Or more like a filesystem, wherein, there are 'directories' down to the bottom level, then you have 'files'?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: To further explain; it's a geographical tree with countries, provinces, cities etc. Thanks for the replies so far.

Comment: "geographical tree with countries, provinces, cities etc." This is a very important information and should be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'll do is to use ltree format, parent ids separated by comma, or any other separator. If you will read from the table and need good performance, you can try to create 6 columns, one for each depth. For the child you will have depth1 = 11, depth2 = 11.16, depth3 = 11.16.20 and so on. This can be indexed better than to use wildcard in the where clause.

If possible, I'll cache the result into redis/memcache. Another option is to use different database, which will be able to handle this better.

Try to have a look at Postgres ltree http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html. You should be able to use it in similar way on mysql.

Comment: And tomorrow, he will want a depth of 7.

Comment: The depth might change in the future but it's unlikely for as far as I can oversee right now. But maybe a new level of granularity can be added. I like the suggested approach, haven't thought about that earlier. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: We used the depth1, 2,.. columns only for indexing. We were stuck with mysql and performance with like was terrible. We created columns only for depth 3, anything below was handled by whole path. The query looked like ... WHERE depth3 = 'A.B.C' AND path LIKE 'A.B.C.D.E.%'. For depth3 query analyzer used fast hash index and for path slower b-tree index. But that was performed on less records.

Comment: This has proven to be the way to handle my case. Thanks for sharing. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Genealogy with Persons**

If all levels contain "persons", then I like a single, non-partitioned, table with `id` and `parent_id`.  `parent_id` is 0 for the 'root(s)' but otherwise 'self joins' to `id` in the same table.

I also prefer to do the tree-walk in application code, not SQL.  That is, given an `id`, I will sequentially do up to 5 more queries to find the ancestors.

With that design, "6" is not frozen in concrete (as would 6 columns).

`id` should be the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table.  The table should be InnoDB.  These two things make the lookups particularly efficient.

(Genealogy gets a lot messier because of weddings, divorces, adoptions, partners, etc.)

**Directories/Files** (or Threads/Messages)

If the 'tree' is for nested "directories", then that would be one table, working like the Genealogy, above.  "Files" would be in another table, with `dir_id` pointing into the Directories table.

In this situation, the schema (columns) of the two tables would mostly be different.  This further argues for 2 tables, not 1.

Comment: It's sort of like genealogy, only geographical. Maybe I should've mentioned in the question I realize now. Thanks for your answer. The scenario described first fits best of the two.